# How to explicitly exclude something from the jar

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a web application that builds using maven.

In my pom, how can i explicitly exclude abc.jar at build time if xyz.jar that i need includes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```